# Symfony 4 : slashes unscaped on JSON response

Tags: php, json, symfony, symfony4

Good morning guys,

I have a probleme on my symfony 4 Api.

I should return a json response, but the serializer return a string with slashes. I Don't know how escape it.

Bellow my controller :

```php
use App\Entity\Category;
use App\Form\CategoryType;
use App\Repository\CategoryRepository;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerInterface as SerializerInterfaceAlias;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;

/**
 * Category Controller
 * @Route("/api", name="api_")
 */
class CategoryController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Rest\Get("/categories")
     * @param CategoryRepository $categoryRepository
     * @param SerializerInterfaceAlias $serializer
     */
    public function index(CategoryRepository $categoryRepository, SerializerInterfaceAlias $serializer)
    {
        $jsonContent = $serializer->serialize($categoryRepository->findall(), 'json', ['json_encode_options' => JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES]);
        return $jsonContent;
    }
[....]
}
```

And my return is look like :

```
"[{\"id\":3,\"name\":\"toto\",\"logo\":\"tata\",\"description\":\"lolo\",\"dateCreated\":\"2019-05-09T10:30:39+00:00\"},{\"id\":4,\"name\":\"tata\",\"logo\":\"titi\",\"description\":\"tutu\",\"dateCreated\":\"2019-05-09T10:30:49+00:00\"}]"
```

For information I using **PHP 7.1** & **Symfony 4.2**.

So I want a proper json format... without this slashes :(

Do you have any suggestion ? :)

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I finaly resolve my problem #RubberDuckDebugging

I don't need to use the serializer here. 

I need just to return :


`return $this->json($categoryRepository->findall());`

That's so simple. Sorry :)

Comment: Please write an answer to your own question and then accept it when you can. It will be useful for users that will encounter your same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finaly resolve my problem #RubberDuckDebugging

I don't need to use the serializer here.

I need just to return :

```
return $this->json($categoryRepository->findall());
```

That's so simple. Sorry :)